# jQuery/JS not removing JS functions on HTML wipe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an issue with dynamically loaded content.

I'm using ajax calls to load in HTML content without refresh the browser, and pages have their own JavaScript libraries that need to load in order for them to work. So I embed that JavaScript content into the HTML which I load with ajax.

The problem is, that even though the HTML that had the embeded JavaScript gets removed, the functionality of those JavaScript functions is still loaded no matter if the HTML along with the JavaScript is removed.

That means, that if a certain page is loaded more than once, actions will fire the same amount of times that the pages has been loaded.

How do I make sure that JavaScript libraries get only loaded into the browser once, retaining the functionality of loading the source of the JS libraries with the ajax call, not just having source file links and then loading them again after the ajax call along with the required HTML is loaded? (load the JS files along with/before the HTML is loaded with ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Once you load a JavaScript file into your browser's memory, it remains there until you load another page.

So... it doesn't matter how do you load it (through AJAX, or just once when page load through script link, or just embedding it into your raw HTML), once it's there it will remain there until you go to another page.

If you want your client code to execute only under certain circumstances you need to control that.

From my point of view your best option is to just load once your libraries and determine by code when execution should start, end, and repeat (if needed).

Comment: The problem is, that JavaScript or jQuery put `<script>..</script>` not in the HTML, but in eval. Using firebug I can see my script loaded as `jquery.min.js line 2 eval(1)`. So it just adds these "evals" without looking if the file is the same or not, thus actions fire as many times as the JS files are loaded..

Comment: I fear you'll need to change that on your code and load your scripts normally instead of doing it through the AJAX call